# RF antenna with satisfied impedance matching. Does it work really?

Tags: circuit-analysis, rf, antenna, impedance-matching

Before I start, how I did an impedance matching for the antenna of my RF source, let me show couple pictures, so I can manage what I am talking about. Below there are:

[image: circuit]

[image: result]

The impedance matching components are L1 and C4 respectively. Before I added these ones, I tried to measure how much the circuit resists at a frequency about 100 MHz. So I got the voltage and the current at the line between C1 and L1. So it was possible to get the resistance there. Of course, also the antenna has a resistance. I calculated the impedance with a couple of individual parameters of this antenna by a web site. I converted this complex number to an absolute integer. In conclusion, I have a source and a load impedance. Now, it is time to make an impedance matching. I got this with the website called "omni impedance matching calculator". I entered these resistance values and gave me the values for L1 and C4. I tested the circuit in LTSpice. I was surprised as I had seen the result. Because, I tried the circuit above without impedance matching, the result was frustrating. Now, I have a satisfying good looking RF circuit with a little more power than the previous version.

Can you tell me if this result can be real and how can I obtain the value for C4? This is a very small value, so when you can give me an advice, I would be very happy.

Comment: It would help if you could tell us the impedance of the antenna you are trying to match, and what you believe to be your amplifier output impedance (pre-match circuit).

Comment: The copper antenna is 200mm long, has 2mm diameter and works at 100MHz.

Comment: What impedance do you believe that presents at 100MHz, and what do you think is the output impedance of your amp?

Comment: L1 and C4 are unrealisable at your 100 MHz. This is one of the benefits, and pitfalls, of simulation. You can make very precise, pure components. You can then go down the rabbit hole of designing stuff you can't possibly make in that pure form, and hold stable, and repeatable. To put some meat on that handwaving, 114 uH and 21 fF have an impedance of 74 kohms (sqrt(L/C)). Any practical LC used for antenna matching is going to be in the 10s or maybe 100s of ohms order, anything bigger would be swamped by parasitics.

Comment: Z (antenna)= 0.08219 Ohms  +j 125.531113 Ohms

Comment: The source impedance should be at about ~350 Kohm at the line, I have predicted.